# convert JSON String to the list object in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm still new to the dart flutter. now I'm trying to pull data from the REST API. following the script that I have made:

```
class ChatCard {
  final String chatdetail_id;
  final String chatdetail_userfullname;
  final String chatdetail_userurlphoto;
  final String chatdetail_message;
  final int chatdetail_isread;
  final String chatdetail_datetime;

  ChatCard({
    this.chatdetail_id,
    this.chatdetail_userfullname,
    this.chatdetail_userurlphoto,
    this.chatdetail_message,
    this.chatdetail_isread,
    this.chatdetail_datetime
  });

  factory ChatCard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new ChatCard(
      chatdetail_id : json['chatdetail_id'] as String,
      chatdetail_userfullname : json['chatdetail_userfullname'] as String,
      chatdetail_userurlphoto : json['chatdetail_userurlphoto'] as String,
      chatdetail_message : json['chatdetail_message'] as String,
      chatdetail_isread : json['chatdetail_isread'] as int,
      chatdetail_datetime : json['chatdetail_datetime'] as String
    );
  }
}

class ChatCardList extends StatefulWidget {

  List<ChatCard> chatcard;

  ChatCardList({Key key, this.chatcard}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatCardListState createState() => new _ChatCardListState(chatcard:chatcard);

  ChatCardList.tambah(String message) {
    print("RESULT MESSAGE = " + message); //result on console : [{"createdAt":"2018-08-16T02:38:37.757Z","is_read":1,"_id":"5b74e3ad26c7de02ed664dd2","from_id":"5b74d3f5e0da63027ab03664","from_name":"Ahmad Adiwijaya","from_photo":"","from_device":"Mobile Phone","text":"Kami dari sekolah tinggi yg hanya satu prodi. Apakah lembaga penjaminan mutuh harus 2, yaitu LPM pada level institusi dan UPM pada level prodi?"},{"from_id":"SystemDate","from_name":"System","from_photo":"","text":"2018-08-23T11:26:53.968Z"}]

  }
}
```

My question is, how do I input the 'RESULT MESSAGE' result data above to class `List<ChatCard> chatcard`?

many thank,

Comment: check the post I wrote : https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-fetching-parsing-json-data-c019ddddaa34

Comment: thank you @Michael Lihs,

I have tried the script that you created on the link that you mean. but my question is different, in the script that I have created, I intend to fill in the `List <ChatCard> chatcard` variable in the `tambah` constructor in the `ChatCardList` class, whether it is possible or not, if so how do I do it,

Best regards,

Comment: @DenisRamdan did you find your answer for this question?... I would like to know the answer of this question.. because I have the same question like yours

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting some like this,

```
ChatCardList.tambah(String message) {
  List<ChatCard> chatCardList = message
    .map((chatCardJson) => ChatCard.fromJson(chatCardJson))
    .toList();
  print(chatCardList); // [Instance of 'ChatCard', Instance of 'ChatCard']
}
```

Note: But the `keys` in the json printed in the console and in the `keys` in the `ChatCard` are different. You might have to revisit that.

Comment: sorry @Dinesh Balasubramanian my mistake, the result is String, not array. `[{"createdAt":"2018-08-16T02:38:37.757Z","is_read":1,"_id":"5b74e3ad26c7de02ed664dd2","from_id":"5b74d3f5e0da63027ab03664","from_name":"Ahmad Adiwijaya","from_photo":"","from_device":"Mobile Phone","text":"Kami dari sekolah tinggi yg hanya satu prodi. Apakah lembaga penjaminan mutuh harus 2, yaitu LPM pada level institusi dan UPM pada level prodi?"},{"from_id":"SystemDate","from_name":"System","from_photo":"","text":"2018-08-23T11:26:53.968Z"}]`