# how to create a list from json string in flutter

Tags: string, list, flutter

this question is already asked in here ([convert JSON String to the list object in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225846/convert-json-string-to-the-list-object-in-flutter)) by someone else.. but right now.. I don't get the answer yet.. so is there a way to call `List<LoginRespon>`... I have converted from json respond using https://app.quicktype.io/ and here is the code

```
import 'dart:convert';

LoginRespon loginResponFromJson(String str) => LoginRespon.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginResponToJson(LoginRespon data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class LoginRespon {
    String status;
    Data data;

    LoginRespon({
        this.status,
        this.data,
    });

    factory LoginRespon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginRespon(
        status: json["status"],
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "data": data.toJson(),
    };
}

class Data {
    String resource;
    String unit;
    Data({
        this.resource,
        this.unit,
    });

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        resource: json["resource"],
        unit: json["unit"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "resource": resource,
        "unit": unit,
    };
}
```

and here is the original json data

```
{
  "status":200,
  "data":{
     "resource":"abc",
     "unit":"a"
}
}
```

Comment: please add your JSON too.

Comment: sure, I have edited my question by adding the json data

Comment: I can't find any list in your JSON. you can convert a JSON array to list but there is no JSON array here.

Comment: Hi I just do understand now... I am new in flutter dart... so, to show a list.. my json data have to consists of array.. I can not make a list... if my json data is only consist of object inside object.. am I right if I say like that?

Comment: it is correct. you can check [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) and  [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-parse-json-in-flutter-for-beginners-8074a68d7a79) for learning how to use and convert json in flutter.