# How to handle list model in bloc flutter

Tags: string, list, flutter, bloc

I am trying to use BLOC inside my login page.. but I always get paused on exception that say `Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'List<LoginRespon>' is not a subtype of type 'String')` here is the code

```
isClick == true
                                        ? StreamBuilder(
                                            initialData: bloc.inData(_name.text,_password.text),
                                            stream: bloc.loginData,
                                            builder: (context,
                                                AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                                  print(snapshot.data);
                                                  print('ppp ');

                                                  return Text('ok');
                                                } else
                                                  return Text(snapshot.error
                                                      .toString());
                                            })
                                        : RaisedButton(
                                            child: Text('Login'),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                isClick = true;
                                              });
                                            },
                                          ),
```

and here is bloc file

```
class MyBLoc{

  final _repository = Repository();
  final _loginController = StreamController<String>();
  Stream<String> get loginData => _loginController.stream;

final _name = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _password = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  saving(){
    _repository.saving(_name.value,_password.value);
  }


  inData(String name, String password) async {
// I get paused on exception inside this method...
    String result = await _repository.saving(name, password);
    _loginController.sink.add(result);
  }


  dispose(){
    _input.close();
    _loginController.close();
    _password.close();
  }
}
final bloc = MyBLoc();
```

here is my repository file

```
class Repository{
  static final userAPIProvider = UserProvider();
  Future saving(String name, String password) => userAPIProvider.saving(name, password);
}
```

and here is my provider

```
class UserProvider {
  final _url = '...';
  Future<List<LoginRespon>> saving(String name, String password) async {
    List<LoginRespon> datalogin = [];
    try {
      bool trustSelfSigned = true;
      HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
        ..badCertificateCallback =
            ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => trustSelfSigned);
      IOClient client = new IOClient(httpClient);
      print("cek");
      final response = await client.post(_url,
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
          },
          body: json.encode({
            "name": name,
            "pas": password,
          }));
      Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

      if (responseJson["status"] == "200") {
        datalogin.add(LoginRespon(
            status: responseJson['status'],
            data: Data(
                name: responseJson['data']['name'],
                status: responseJson['data']['status'])));
        return datalogin;
      } else {
        print("ppp");
      }
    } on Exception {
      rethrow;
    }
    return datalogin;
  }}
```

and for my LoginRespon model is available here [how to create a list from json string in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554156/how-to-create-a-list-from-json-string-in-flutter?noredirect=1#comment108888793_61554156)
Paused on exception happens inside bloc file in `inData` method is there a way to resolve this problem `Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'List<LoginRespon>' is not a subtype of type 'String')`

Comment: The code is unclear and messy. I cannot find userAPIProvider.saving method. Is it addSave()

Comment: yes it is.. Ihave edited my code just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MyBloc, the returned value is supposed to be String

```dart
 String result = await _repository.saving(name, password);
```

But it's not the case with the following line in the repository

```dart
Future saving(String name, String password) => userAPIProvider.saving(name, password);
```

It's returning `List<LoginRespon>`

Comment: is there a way to change ```String result``` into List

Comment: Change the  StreamController as per the required data type.